# Как сделать, чтобы государства различались цветовыми оттенками на карте?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Раньше (пару лет назад), просматривать Карты Европы и Азии, а так же пограничных стран России было гораздо удобнее и понятнее, когда Государства различались разными цветовыми оттенками. Сейчас такого нет. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт о сервисе [Яндекс.Карты](https://yandex.ru/maps/), то дизайн картографической подложки выбирает сам сервис и настроить его нельзя. Вы можете написать им свои пожелания в поддержку.

На своём сайте при использовании Карт через API, вы можете использовать [модуль "Регионы"](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/regions-docpage/?from=SO). C его помощью можно отобразить территориальное деление поверх карты и раскрасить в свои цвета. В песочнице есть [пример создания политической карты](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/regions_colors?from=SO).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]